# Why do we have separate user accounts across Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, user-accounts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why separate Stack Exchange accounts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69422/why-separate-stack-exchange-accounts)

I don't quite know where to post a question about Stack Exchange itself, but here it goes.

I use several of the Stack Exchange sites, including GIS and Server Fault, but I need to have a separate user account for each of these sites. Why is that? Wouldn't it be great to have a single Stack Exchange account you can use to track your activities across all sites?

Comment: Better asked on meta.stackoverflow.com

Comment: There is a "meta" site link in the banner of every stack exchange site for questions about the site, rather than questions about the topic of the site. At the very least, this question belongs there.