# Multiple accounts for every Stack Exchange network site?

Tags: discussion

I just joined stackoverflow.com and have found that, if I wanted to use the other Stack Exchange sites like programmers, meta, photography, etc., for each one I have to create a new account. Why can't I have one account for all the sites belonging to Stack Exchange. I understand that badges from one site are not applicable to other sites, but how about generic badges or military-like decorations?

Answer (score 5):

There isn't one account. Your accounts are linked instead.

Log in with the **same** OpenID, email, etc you used on stackoverflow, on any other stackexchange website and it will ask if you want to link up your related accounts.

Then, if you goto your profile you'll see : *Stats|Prefs|**Accounts*** With all your accounts on the stackexchange network.

Most users here have accounts linked up. You can also have your bio copied across all sites.

Comment: If (which is to be expected) one uses the very same OpenID account, and associates the accounts when prompted to do so.

Comment: I see. In that case what is it linked to ? Meaning whats the master account and how do I access it ??

Comment: Yes I _marked_ the answer then edited it =P Hoping to be the FGITW but seems its been 8 mins and I'm the only answer. Hmm Meta is different....

Comment: @user I updated my answer.

Comment: @user also see this question for WHY there are separate accounts (Which are linked) http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69422/why-separate-stack-exchange-accounts

Comment: Thanx...I guess I am confused by the fact that every time I goto a new site I am asked to login ( I use my gmail/google account) to sign in, and once I provide it, it then asks me to create a account using open id. if I used my gmail account where is this open ID coming from and more importantly how do I find my open ID

Comment: @user - the accounts are just linked to each other. There's no "master" as such, except perhaps the one with the most reputation.

Comment: @user this might help : http://technofriends.in/2008/11/10/what-is-openid-and-how-to-use-your-gmail-account-as-openid/

Comment: @giddy thanks - the technofriends link helped.

Comment: You're welcome! I found the OpenID bit confusing myself. I remember creating some duplicate a/c or something. That's why I googled and came across that article! =P