# Universal login throughout all Stack Exchange sites

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange, login, user-accounts

I have started using more Stack Exchange sites. Whenever I go to a new site I have to login and create an account. I think it would be more convenient if when you create a 
Stack Exchange account, it creates an inactive account on all of the sites. Then when you go and click on one you are already logged in. A sort of universal login idea.

Comment: No thanks, I don't need an account on *every - single - site*.

Comment: It's only a one-time action which should take you no more than a couple of clicks. Is that really so much of a bother?

Comment: Also, welcome to Meta! Please do not be discouraged that your question has been proposed as a duplicate. Sometimes questions are hard to locate; experienced folks have an easier time doing that. And please do note that [downvotes work a bit differently here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta)—in particular, they are often used to indicate *disagreement* with a proposed feature request like this one. They don't necessarily mean that you asked a bad question and should go bury your head in shame. :-)

Comment: looking at "Why separate Stack Exchange accounts?" It seams like something more logical would to use the stack exchange account as something more like an openid system. Also reputation flowing might be possible through some things like sites with having to do with programing. as said by [Eugene](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/174732/eugene)

Answer (score 3):

The Stack Exchange network currently includes [105 sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites), with an additional 554 more proposals in [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/).

I visit three sites on a regular basis, have posted questions or answers on six, and have visited a couple of dozen. The suggested change would mean that 100+ or 600+ accounts would be created on my behalf, the vast majority of which I will never use. Some people use more than me, of course, but I can't imagine many people using enough of the sites on a regular enough basis to warrant the overhead that would be created by this change.

Comment: It would also be sort of weird/confusing to have users listed in the "Users" list for a site that *had never logged on* (nor had any intention to do so).

Comment: Maybe when you are creating a account for a site it would just create it based on your stackexchange account. Instead of creating a lot of accounts.

Comment: @Noah I would be more in favor of something like that, but then we would need additional changes to support the functionality to allow users to maintain different profile information on the various sites. Will you elaborate on the problem you see with the current system that needs to be corrected?

Comment: @GeorgeCummins as [Jose_GD](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/166883/jose-gd) said [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69422/why-separate-stack-exchange-accounts) sometimes you create an account with a diferent google acount or not a google acount at all. Instead you could use the stackexchange id as a openid when you login to an account.

Comment: @GeorgeCummins It would _remove_ all but one (so in your case removing 5 of the 6). The one account would work on all 6 of the sites you use.