# Why do I need to make an account for each SE Site?

Tags: feature-request, user-accounts

Its a minor nuisance, but its still a nuisance. Everyone once in a while Ill find a new SE site that looks interesting or that Ill have a comment for, but when I go to make the comment, the system asks me to make an account. Generally, its a very small comment and I'm too lazy to make an account for that.

What I don't understand is why I need to make an account every time. They all get linked anyways, so why isn't it just assumed we have an account everywhere?

**Edit:** For those who think that this is a bad idea because (1) some users don't want to associate with some site, (2) it would ruin site's user statistics or (3) it would spam their communities list, this can be avoided by doing this with a 'copy-on-write' mentality. In other words, you wouldn't actually have an account on the site until you performed your first action. Then an account would be created and linked for you instantly and (more importantly) seamlessly. This means (1) you aren't part of the community unless your actually part of the community, (2) the sites don't get the user statistics until they actually get the user, and (3) you dont see a massive list of communities your part of until you are actually part of those communities.

Comment: Because many people don't want to have an account on both Islam *and* Christianity *and* Mi Yodea.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thats silly. This point is not that you have one account everywhere, the point is you have one account period. It works everywhere, but it doesn't mean your part of everything.

Comment: @lostsock That question seems to be refreshing to the auto-login feature that requires you to refresh your page. I'm talking about account creation, not logging in.

Comment: @Dgrin91: then how'd any site track their own community? Or track per-site stats for any account? You need an account on each site for that part.

Comment: Also of: [Why separate Stack Exchange accounts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/69422)

Comment: @MartijnPieters Easy, you only track users with activity. Essentially a copy-on-write model. Your account is already set up to interact with the site at any time, and the first time you actually do something a 'write' (or in this case an account creation) will occur.

Comment: @Dgrin91: It is *trivial* to create a new account on a new site; I much rather have this an explicit step than it being implicit.

Comment: @Dgrin91: besides, you are assuming everyone wants their accounts to be associated. Not everyone wants this. Perhaps they want their gamer side to be anonymous, or want to use an anonymous account on Workplace to deal with boss-employee issues they don't want their boss to find out about.

Comment: @MartijnPieters That all fine. Your all points are taken. Let user customize there look in different websites. All I suggest is I am logged in to one site of SE network and I open another, it should just let me in, as new user, without asking for signup. That's all.

Comment: @rptwsthi: yes, I understood that, and there are good reasons that that doesn't work like that right now. Creating a new account is as simple as clicking 'log in' and providing OpenID credentials you used elsewhere on the network. You'll be asked to confirm you want an account created, and that's it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: You mentioned, "I understood that, and there are good reasons that that doesn't work like that right now". If those, good reasons are not secret, please reveal. And on your suggestion, we even create account with 30 fields to fill, whenever needed.